# SEO - numbers as numerals or words?

Tags: seo

Fairly straightforward question. I am building a site for a cycle holiday company. Something they offer is 2 day breaks. I want to emphasise this for the purposes of SEO. Does anyone know if google equates '2' with 'two', '3' with 'three' etc? If numbers are an important part of the essence of what a page is about, then do I need to ensure I include both the numeral and word versions of numbers in my titles & META desc/keywords?

Cheers.

Comment: ... or for that matter, in the text on the page itself. I've just typed '2 day breaks' & 'two day breaks' into google and noticed it gives slightly different results. My guess is that google makes the connection, but still they are not equal?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use "Two" in the page title and "2" in the page text.  This is more for human usability than search engine optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search engines know 2 means "two" and 3 means "three", etc. So there's no need to favor one over the other for SEO purposes.

FYI, Meta tags do not affect ranking so I wouldn't worry about them too much. Make a good Meta description as they *may* be shown in the search results (without affecting your ranking). The keyword tag is literally useless.

Comment: Thanks, John. So you are saying that it makes not a blind bit of difference whether I promote the page as '2 day breaks' or 'two day breaks', correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay dokes. Cheers.